# Can a MongoDB query keep track of previous document?

Tags: mongodb

I want to build a query where I in the `$project` stage of an aggregation set a key to `true` or `false` based on the previous document's data.

This is the structure I'm looking for:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5a79725a2ca81e5b7f84ef50",
    "name": "Lola",
    "hasDog": true,
    "neighbourWithDog": false,
    "address": "1st Street"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a79725a5933283ab266e006",
    "name": "Nick",
    "hasDog": false,
    "neighbourWithDog": true,
    "address": "1st Street"
  }
]
```

Where the field `neghbourWithDog` is based on whether `hasDog` is set to true or false in the previous document.

I can easily do this after the response from the database, building a new response through loops and if statements, but when the data starts to pile up, the app (Node JS) becomes very slow.

So I'm wondering if it's even possible to perform such a query? I do realise that the documents can come in any order, so I’d have to sort them first.

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly you could perhaps try `$addFields`. If you provide your query and an example of the end result I could try and provide a complete answer

Comment: Your suggestion is a help along the way. I’ve updated the question with some more info

Comment: thanks for the updated question. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Two ways. First via `$project` and the second via `$addFields`. Both use the `$cond` to check if the `"hasDog"` is `true` or `false`.

My documents look like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7996911f496a82583c265a"),
    "name" : "Lola",
    "hasDog" : true,
    "address" : "1st Street"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7996971f496a82583c266a"),
    "name" : "Nick",
    "hasDog" : false,
    "address" : "1st Street"
}
```

`$project` way:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
{ $project : 
  { _id : 0, 
    neighbourWithDog : 
     {  $cond: 
        { if: 
          { $eq : [ "$hasDog", true ] }, then: true, else: false } 
        }
     }
  }
])
```

outputs:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "neighbourWithDog" : true
}

/* 2 */
{
    "neighbourWithDog" : false
}
```

Or the `$addFileds` way:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
{ $addFields: 
   { neighbourWithDog : 
     {  $cond: 
        { if: { $eq : [ "$hasDog", true ] }, then: "true", else: "false" } 
        }
     }
   }
])
```

Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7996911f496a82583c265a"),
    "name" : "Lola",
    "hasDog" : true,
    "address" : "1st Street",
    "neighbourWithDog" : "true"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7996971f496a82583c266a"),
    "name" : "Nick",
    "hasDog" : false,
    "address" : "1st Street",
    "neighbourWithDog" : "false"
}
```

Please note that if you don't want the string `"true"` or `"false"` then remove the `" "` and you'll have the `Boolean` value instead, like the `$projection` example does